# Load the properties file from external directory

Tags: java, properties

Currently I am loading the property files from the Resource Stream like this-

```
prop.load(LoadTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("database.properties"));
```

But what I am looking for is if there is any way I can load the property files from any external directory. Suppose my `database.properties` file is in-

`C:\logging-test\database.properties`

Then how can I load the above property file from that location? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @madth3 stated, you can use the other overload of the load() method in the Properties object to pass an InputStream referencing to a file in the filesystem:

```
prop.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\logging-test\\database.properties"));
```